# How to delete a Linked Service in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Data Factory pipeline that contains a bunch of Linked Services. Some of them are not used anymore and I would like to delete them. However, when I try to delete some of them, Data Factory complains that it is still used with the following error:

> Error: Not able to delete linked service, message returned from
>   service - The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by
>   staging_zone_dim.

[image: Error]

**Question**

I made sure that no Datasets or Pipelines references it and still, I do get the error message when I try to delete the linked services. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to work around this issue by directly going to the Git repository that contained the `json` files and deleting the unused configuration files.

Comment: This issue (as mentioned by @simon-zeinstra) for managing multiple places is coming to an end . 

As per Microsoft Notification --> You have GIT enabled in your data factory. Publishing outside GIT mode, when you have GIT enabled, will be disabled July 31st 2019.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look in the published view of the data factory and delete the pipelines there too before deleting the linked service.

You can switch here by choosing data factory instead of Azure DevOps:

[image]

Comment: How can I have a look at the published view of the data factory? Also, I do not understand why whatever I am doing a specific branch of the pipeline would be linked to the stuff already published...

Comment: I've added a picture showing you how to switch to the published data factory. I'm not 100% sure this will solve your problem, but since you are sure that your have deleted all of the referenced pipelines / datasets, there must be another place where the data factory finds this reference.

Answer (score 1):

In ADF UI, go to Manage (Left bar, briefcase with a wrench inside), and select linked services

[image]

After that, pass the cursor over the service you want to delete, and select the trash can logo.

[image]